# Pivot longer in R with Multiple Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I have the following data. Each row is one school where students are interviewed. A brief snipped of data is pasted below

```
df <- data.frame(
  school = c("School 1", "School 2", "School 3"),
  Student1_Name = c("Name1A", "Name1B", "Name1C"),
  Student1_Resp1 = c(1,1,2),
  Student1_Resp2 = c(2,1,2),
  Student2_Name = c("Name2A", "Name2B", "Name2C"),
  Student2_Resp1 = c(2,2,2),
  Student2_Resp2 = c(1,2,1)
)

> df1
    school Student1_Name Student1_Resp1 Student1_Resp2 Student2_Name Student2_Resp1 Student2_Resp2
1 School 1        Name1A              1              2        Name2A              2              1
2 School 2        Name1B              1              1        Name2B              2              2
3 School 3        Name1C              2              2        Name2C              2              1
```

I want to use `pivot_longer` to change the data like below

```
    school Student_Name Student_Resp1 Student_Resp2
1 School 1       Name1A             1             2
2 School 1       Name2A             2             1
3 School 2       Name1B             1             1
4 School 2       Name2B             2             2
5 School 3       Name1C             2             2
6 School 3       Name2C             2             1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know regex abit:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, -school,  names_to = ".value", names_pattern = '_(.*)',
                names_transform = ~str_c('Student_',.))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  school   Student_Name Student_Resp1 Student_Resp2
  <chr>    <chr>                <dbl>         <dbl>
1 School 1 Name1A                   1             2
2 School 1 Name2A                   2             1
3 School 2 Name1B                   1             1
4 School 2 Name2B                   2             2
5 School 3 Name1C                   2             2
6 School 3 Name2C                   2             1
```

if you dont know regex:

```
df %>%
   pivot_longer(-school,  names_to = c(NA,  ".value"), 
                names_sep = '_', names_transform = ~str_c('Student_',.))
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  school   Student_Name Student_Resp1 Student_Resp2
  <chr>    <chr>                <dbl>         <dbl>
1 School 1 Name1A                   1             2
2 School 1 Name2A                   2             1
3 School 2 Name1B                   1             1
4 School 2 Name2B                   2             2
5 School 3 Name1C                   2             2
6 School 3 Name2C                   2             1
```

Comment: This is much better than my approach.

Comment: Thanks. This is very efficient. Can you please add a little explanation about the regex names_pattern method? I want to implement this on a bigger data with slightly different column names. Much appreciated

Comment: @UmerNaeem The best I can do is direct you to regex places. Start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax). Regex is a whole language by itself. and the symbols I used are metacharacters

Answer (score 2):

I think the desired output is missing an `id` column, but the below should work (we could of course drop the `id` column if it is not necessary):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rename_with(~gsub("^(Student)(\\d+)_(.*)$","\\1_\\3__\\2", .x), starts_with("Student")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -school,
               names_to = c(".value", "id"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)__(.*)$")

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   school   id    Student_Name Student_Resp1 Student_Resp2
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>                <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 School 1 1     Name1A                   1             2
#> 2 School 1 2     Name2A                   2             1
#> 3 School 2 1     Name1B                   1             1
#> 4 School 2 2     Name2B                   2             2
#> 5 School 3 1     Name1C                   2             2
#> 6 School 3 2     Name2C                   2             1
```

Data from the OP

```r
df <- data.frame(
  school = c("School 1", "School 2", "School 3"),
  Student1_Name = c("Name1A", "Name1B", "Name1C"),
  Student1_Resp1 = c(1,1,2),
  Student1_Resp2 = c(2,1,2),
  Student2_Name = c("Name2A", "Name2B", "Name2C"),
  Student2_Resp1 = c(2,2,2),
  Student2_Resp2 = c(1,2,1)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>